# In Intellij Translation Editor, how do I jump / go forward to the next item?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, intellij-14

IntelliJ and Android Studio have a great "Translation Editor" where it shows you all the `<string>` entries of the `strings.xml` and you can add items and locales on the fly. It also shows which strings are not translated yet and offers a blank box to enter the translation

To use this rapidly, I would like to go from one string entry directly to the next without needing to switch to the mouse, hover around and double-click on the next item. It looks like this:

[image]

I think this is something any user would love. I was surprised when I couldn't make it happen. I can move to the next row via <kbd>Enter</kbd> but that row is then only focused, not selected and I can't type. I tried <kbd>Enter</kbd> again, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd> and many many many more keyboard combinations. Still no success

**So: How can I either move to the next item directly or select a focused item in the Translation Editor?**

My version is 14.1.4

Answer (score 0):

To select a focused item press <kbd>F2</kbd> (working in Translation Editor on Android Studio 2.2)